# making custom copy and paste menu appear when text is selected

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to create a custom copy and paste menu in the Action bar but when I select the text in the EditText area the default copy and paste menu will pop up, but when I long press the EditText area instead of the text, the custom menu appears in the Action bar. How can I have my custom copy and paste menu appear when the text is selected?

I looked at this similar question [Override the general paste context menu in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759409/override-the-general-paste-context-menu-in-android)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText Input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Input);
    Input.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View p1)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                startActionMode(new ActionBarCallBack());
                return false;
            }
        });
}

class ActionBarCallBack implements ActionMode.Callback
{


    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item)
    {           
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.copyText:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.pasteText:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Paste", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.cutText:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cut", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.help:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Help", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return false;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try Using [setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback%28android.view.ActionMode.Callback%29) 
instead of setOnLongClickListener()

Comment: how can I achieve on the case of webview?

Answer (score 0):

A full sample bellow. In my case it was to add a "**Scan with camera**" context menu. Note that this solution doesn't override the context menu of a text selected within the EditText:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    cbEditText.setCustomInsertionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            menu.add(0, 1, 0, R.string.edt_scan_camera);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            if (1 == item.getItemId()) {
                //todo: perform your action here!
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    });
}
```