# Android Studio, how to change the pop up list of option after highliting a text or a word

Tags: android, android-studio

usually when we highliting a word on phone, it will have a pop up list that contain function like copy, paste, search such functions. Is it able to change the pop up list so that i can modify it to other function？

Comment: Does this answer your question? [making custom copy and paste menu appear when text is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298226/making-custom-copy-and-paste-menu-appear-when-text-is-selected)

Answer (score 0):

Check about [ActionMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode) APIs. You can remove all functions and add custom function.